# Observed voltage unexpected in simple test circuit with one resistor

Tags: voltage-measurement, ohms-law

I have a 1.65v regulated source (max 50mA).
I'm observing 1.71v with no load.

I've added a 178 ohm resistor (verified with VOM).
I'm observing 1.60v 9mA across the resistor pins.
V = IR; V = .009A x 178o; V = 1.60v

**Why am I observing 1.60v instead of 1.71?**  I'm not expecting any voltage drop.

I attach a device with unknown impedance in place of the resistor above.
I'm observing 1.63v 1.6mA
R = V/I; R = 1.63/.0016; R = 1019 ohms.

But again, **why am I observing 1.63v instead of 1.71?**

This is how I created the test on my test bench, including the VOM.
As described above, my VOM gets a different reading than the simulator.

UPDATE:
Photo 2: Test bench - 3.26v supply 1.65 reg - measure at source pins.
Photo 3: Test bench - measure across load pins (no load present).
Photo 4: Test bench - measure across load pins (178o resistor).

[image]

[image: Test Bench - supply + regulator]

[image: Test Bench - no load]

[image: Test Bench - with 178o resistor]

Comment: Clearly it's not a very well regulated source.

Comment: @Hearth, could it be that simple?

"... the 39150 offers extremely low dropout (typically .375mV at 1.5A)..."

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic39150.pdf

Comment: What voltage do you measure if you connect the VOM directly to the output of the supply instead of across the resistor? They may appear to be at the same voltage, but with a breadboard, there is non-zero resistance in the jumper wires and breadboard connections.

Comment: Is an ammeter placed in series with resistor during measurement?

Comment: .375mV means diff. between Vin and Vout. Not a drop because of loading.

Comment: I guess it is a mix of both, a little voltage inaccuracy at the source and some resistance in the jumper connections. That can easily get up to a couple mV error.

Comment: I'm wondering if the regulator is within spec at these observed values?  The data sheet notes that 10mA load is required (mine appears to be 1.6mA), else leakage resulting in higher voltage (mine is lower under load).  Direct output to the VOM is 1.71v, same as points on the board.  Ammeter was not connected at time of voltage measurement (only have a single VOM).

Comment: Note 2 from the datasheet: "the device is not guaranteed to function outside its operating rating". Furthermore, the voltmeters could be off by a few mV, the multimeter could be off by a few mA (have you calibrated all of them to a known standard?). Differences of a few tens of mV with hobby-grade equipment would not surprise me. You have not tested this circuit within its normal operating condition. What does the output do when you draw 100mA?

Comment: Ignore the breadboard and show the volt meter into the voltage supply. Do they show the same voltage? If not then one of them is inaccurate. Certain regulators require a minimum load to operate properly, but that shouldn't be the case for a commercial bench supply.

Comment: The datasheet says 375 mV, not .375 mV. The latter would be truly impressive, and I doubt anything can actually reach that. Besides, you're misunderstanding what dropout voltage is, as Michal pointed out.

Comment: Added test bench photos: 1) Vreg measured at regulator pins, 2) measure across load pins (no load present), 3) measure across load pins (178o resistor present).   I'm sorry, I don't know how to simulate a 100mA load?

Answer (score 0):

**You are operating the Mic39150 outside of its guaranteed limits!**

According to the [datasheet of MIc39150](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic39150.pdf), on page 4 in table on row with parameter "Minimum load current": 7 mA typical, but 10 mA Max.

So below 10 mA load current any good behavior is just luck.